# Dotfill after hypenation break

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, hyphenation, dotfill

It seems there is an issue with `\dotfill` after a hyphenation break, minimal example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus
\dotfill 23 24 25
\end{document}
```

processed with **pdflatex** produces

[image]

Any ideas?

*Note, this post replaces an earlier post which included details which I later found were not relevant to the problem.*

Comment: This deserves the tag "tex-core" although the OP is likely not aware of that.

Comment: Added, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX tries to avoid that line before the paragraph end has a hyphen. You can allow that by changing `\finalhyphendemerits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus \dotfill 
23 24 25 

\finalhyphendemerits =0 hippopotamus, hippopotamus, hippopotamus, 
hippopotamus, hippopotamus \dotfill 23 24 25 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fabulous, fixes the problem from which the minimal example was derived -- many thanks!